# What is the most efficient way to count values in this dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe containing maybe ~200k words and phrases.  Many of the phrases are duplicative (e.g., the word "adventure" appears thousands of times).  I'd like to get a count of each word, and then dedupe.  My attempts at doing so take a really long time--longer than anything else in the entire script--and doing anything with the resulting dataframe after I've gotten my counts also takes forever.

My initial input looks like this:

```
Keyword_Type    Keyword     Clean_Keyword
Not Geography   cat         cat
Not Geography   cat         cat
Not Geography   cat         cat
Not Geography   cats        cat
Not Geography   cave        cave
Not Geography   celebrity   celebrity
Not Geography   celebrities celebrity
```

I'm looking for an output like this, which counts all of the times that a given word appears in the dataframe.

```
Keyword_Type    Keyword     Clean_Keyword   Frequency
Not Geography   cat         cat             4 
Not Geography   cat         cat             4
Not Geography   cat         cat             4
Not Geography   cats        cat             4
Not Geography   cave        cave            1
Not Geography   celebrity   celebrity       2
Not Geography   celebrities celebrity       2
```

The code snippet I'm currently using is as follows:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("Clean_Keyword")
key_count = key_lemma.select("Keyword_Type","Keyword", "Clean_Keyword", count("Clean_Keyword").over(w).alias("Frequency")).dropDuplicates()
```

I also tried a `groupby`-`count` on the Clean Keyword column and joining back to the original key_count df, but this also takes a disgustingly large amount of time.  The functions on this same dataset before counting and deduping run in a second or two or less, and any subsequent functions I run on the resulting df are faster on my computer using straight Python than PySpark running on a decent-sized cluster.  So, needless to say, something I'm doing is definitely not optimal...

Comment: I don't understand how those frequency numbers are made. Where is the text? In the keyword column?

Comment: I created them through the partition function.  The dataset here isn't sorted, but adventure might appear thousands of times further down within my dataset.  I windowed on the keyword and counted the rows within.  Windows are created based on the keyword and rows within counted.  Hope that answers your question--not sure if that was the source of confusion or not!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you shouldn't need to join after the `groupby` and `count`. Group by all three columns, not just `Clean_Keyword`.

Comment: Are you trying to count from *anywhere* in the dataframe? Does case matter? Can you make a smaller example, perhaps?

Comment: Just updated with a hopefully better example.  I don't think grouping by all 3 columns will work, since I'm interested in the number of clean_keyword values specifically.  I also need to keep the other two columns for later.

Comment: Okay, I see. I think the `groupby` followed by `count` and then a join is the way to go. If the number of distinct `clean_keyword`s is small, you can do a broadcast join and save yourself the shuffle. Can you tell if you have a partition that is lagging behind the others?

Comment: How would I determine if there is a particular partition lagging behind the others?  I am leaning towards this as the reason, since it just doesn't make sense why running the uncounted dataset earlier in the script would take so little time, and yet this step and everything after is like molasses, even on simple functions like display() on already computed variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your window function solution is going to be the most efficient, a join implies 2 sorts whereas a window only implies one. You may be able to optimize by doing a `groupBy` before windowing instead of a `dropDuplicates` after:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("Clean_Keyword")
key_count  = key_lemma\
    .groupBy(key_lemma.columns)\
    .agg(psf.count("*").alias("Frequency"))\
    .withColumn("Frequency", psf.sum("Frequency").over(w))
key_count.show()

    +-------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
    | Keyword_Type|    Keyword|Clean_Keyword|Frequency|
    +-------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
    |Not Geography|       cave|         cave|        1|
    |Not Geography|        cat|          cat|        4|
    |Not Geography|       cats|          cat|        4|
    |Not Geography|  celebrity|    celebrity|        2|
    |Not Geography|celebrities|    celebrity|        2|
    +-------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

This will be more efficient especially if you have a lot of lines but not so many distinct keys (most `Keywords` are equal to their `Clean_Keyword`)

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, this approach takes even longer :(  I killed it after 10 minutes; the approach I was using took ~3-4.  Is the efficiency meant to be gained through the groupby?  (Not asking this in an accusatory way, just curious.)

Comment: It will depend on your data but if you have a lot of `Keywords` equal to there `Clean_Keyword` the groupBy will reduce the number of lines significantly. Therefore you'll have fewer lines for the window function computation